# PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

This file I am using but I got this **warning**.

The script is **running okay**. But I want to get rid of the message.

The line : `$myObj->afstand= $formattedNum . " km";` gives the warning.

I've tried to make a new class, but nothing works.

Does someone know how to get rid of the warning?

```
 <?php
      $lat1= $_POST['lat1'];
      $lon1= $_POST['lon1'];

      $lat2= $_POST['lat2'];
      $lon2= $_POST['lon2'];


     $lat3= $_POST['lat1'];
     $lon3= $_POST['lon1'];

     $lat4= $_POST['lat2'];
     $lon4= $_POST['lon2'];

    $unit = "K";

    function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

           $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
           $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
           $dist = acos($dist);
           $dist = rad2deg($dist);
           $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
           $unit = strtoupper($unit);

           if ($unit == "K") {
              return ($miles * 1.609344);
           } else if ($unit == "N") {
              return ($miles * 0.8684);
           } else {
                return $miles;
              }
       }

        $formattedNum = number_format(distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "K"), 1);


        $myObj->afstand= $formattedNum . " km";

        $a = $lat3;
        $a .= ",";
        $a .=$lon3;

        $myObj->saddr = $a;

        $myObj->nwlat = $lat3;
        $myObj->nwlon = $lon3;

        $myObj->nwlat2 = $lat4;
        $myObj->nwlon2 = $lon4;

        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

        echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `$myObj`? I think you forgot to initialize it.

```php
$myObj = new stdClass();
```

or better define your class with its properties like:

```php
final class MyObj
{
    public $afstand;
    public $saddr;

    public $nwlat;
    public $nwlat2;

    public $nwlon;
    public $nwlon2;
}
```

Saying that I suggest you improve the names for your properties. 
What does "afstand" stand for? And what about the "nw" prefix for "lat & lon" properties?

Use intention revealing, pronounceable and searchable names: https://github.com/Chemaclass/php-best-practices/blob/master/technical-skills/meaningful-names.md

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to declare and assign `myObj` variable.

```php
$myObj = new stdClass();
// $myObj->afstand = '';
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I don't see the error message again.